# Redirect in flask

Tags: python, flask

I am not sure, why the page gets redirected to /index route once the username is input

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, request
from markupsafe import escape

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set the secret key to some random bytes. Keep this really secret!
app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return 'Logged in as %s' % escape(session['username'])
    return 'You are not logged in'

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['username'] = request.form['username']
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return '''
        <form method="post">
            <p><input type=text name=username>
            <p><input type=submit value=Login>
        </form>
    '''

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # remove the username from the session if it's there
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

The code is from quickstart documentation of flask

Comment: your login view function returns a redirect to `url_for('index')`...

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 i can understand that for POST menthod, but i was actually talking about:     return '''
        <form method="post">
            <p><input type=text name=username>
            <p><input type=submit value=Login>
        </form>
    '''

Comment: When you submit the form, it will send a POST request to the server, and this will be handled under the `if request.method == POST`, so you will then be redirected.

Comment: Where do you want the users redirect to if login is successful?

Comment: @SeyiDaniel its not my code, i just picked it from Flask documentation. I got my doubts why the page gets redirected once user, enters username

Answer (score 0):

Actually, @monsieuralfonse64 has already given the answer, so I just summary it.

Since your form sets `method="post"` attribute:

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # ...
    return '''
        <form method="post">
            <p><input type=text name=username>
            <p><input type=submit value=Login>
        </form>
    '''
```

When you submit the form, the browser will send the data as POST method, that's why it triggers the `if request.method == 'POST':` statement, then execute `return redirect(url_for('index'))`, finally your page redirect to /index.